# Is there a way to change the CSS attribute of parent level item, when hover child element using CSS?

Tags: css

```
<div class="menu-create-content__main-item">main item</div>

<div class="menu-create-content__sub-items">
  <div class="menu-create-content__sub-item">sub item1</div>
  <div class="menu-create-content__sub-item">sub item2</div>
  <div class="menu-create-content__sub-item">sub item3</div>
</div>
```

I need to change the `background-color` of the `menu-create-content__main-item` when mouse hover on `menu-create-content__sub-item` using CSS.

Comment: Not possible atm.

Comment: Possible by using js or jquery...

Comment: Obligatory link: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1016716)

Comment: @MrLister, it seems that OP wants to target the previous sibling, not the parent of the hovered element itself.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn No, they want to target the previous sibling _of_ the parent of the hovered element.

Comment: @MrLister, yes, but it means that even if _there were_ a parent selector, it wouldn't solve the problem. Hovewer, the generic `:has()` selector (from the Selectors Level 4), if implemented, could do this.

Comment: Is there any reason why the hover needs to be on `..._sub-item` and cannot be on the wrapper `..._sub-items` ? There are dirty tricks like absolute positioned `:before` elements or misusing inputs and labels. But javascript is much cleaner here.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible now. You can do this using `jquery`. On `mouseover` you can add class to `menu-create-content__main-item` and to this class add styles with `background-color`

Comment: I'm considering Only using CSS. Thanks.